# How to change tabs' strings orientation?

Tags: javafx-2

When use TabPane with tabs placed on sides the tabs' headers and strings rotates and has vertical orientation. Is there any way to place tabs' string horizontally when use TabPane with the right/left sided tabs?

Comment: Put string as label into graphic node. Graphic node can be rotated (there is a rotate graphic property of the tab)

Comment: Maybe I didn't catch the idea, but how can I use graphic node as a tab header?

Comment: instead of tab.setText("Text") use tab.setGraphic(new Label("Text")), and look at TabPane.rotateGraphic property

Comment: And is it possible by FXML?

Comment: Yes. You need to specify attribute rotateGraphic of tabPane, if needed, and set property graphic of a tab to a new instance of label, and that is all.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you a lot! But now I have another question - is there a way to make tab autoresize considering node size or it's necessary to set value of TabMinWidth manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put string as label into graphic node. Graphic node can be rotated (there is a rotate graphic property of the tabpane)

Specifically, instead of tab.setText("Text") use tab.setGraphic(new Label("Text")), and look at TabPane.rotateGraphic property.

If you want implementation via fxml : then yes, it is possible. You need to specify attribute rotateGraphic of tabPane, if needed, and set property graphic of a tab to a new instance of label, and that is all. Mostly all you can do via java-code, you can repeat via fxml.

Talking about tabMinWidth - I think, you should look at binding expressions here : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html
Specifically, I think, you should be interested in max() method - you need to have max of widths of all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in this way ...

#### Set following CSS for Tab pane in .CSS file

-fx-tab-min-width: 30px; 
-fx-tab-max-width: 30px; 
-fx-tab-min-height: 130px;
-fx-tab-max-height: 130px;

#### After that set label in Tab graphics,
Set Min Width for label (Must require)